# how to Get the Dual Monitor is available or Get the Full Width including Dual Monitor in VB6

Tags: vb6, multiple-monitors

I am facing an issue with Dual Monitors in **VB6**, Please help me to find out the any one the following.

1. Either get the Dual Monitor is connected or not?
2. Get the Full Width of Screen (Primary Screen + Extended Monitor Screen)

Currently I am using the existing Properties available in VB6.

`Screen.Width` & `Screen.Height` which gives me only the Primary Monitor's Width and Height.

Comment: Here is a [nice article](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/vsm20090302.pdf) by Karl Peterson on coding for multiple monitors in VB6, with some [ready-to-use code](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/Monitors/) which you can drop into your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use Windows API to determine the virtual screen size for a multi-monitor setup:

```
Private Const SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN = 78
Private Const SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN = 79
Private Const SM_CMONITORS = 80
Private Const SM_SAMEDISPLAYFORMAT = 81

Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" ( _
   ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Public Property Get VirtualScreenWidth() As Long
   VirtualScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
End Property
Public Property Get VirtualScreenHeight() As Long
   VirtualScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
End Property
Public Property Get DisplayMonitorCount() As Long
   DisplayMonitorCount = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS)
End Property
Public Property Get AllMonitorsSame() As Long
   AllMonitorsSame = GetSystemMetrics(SM_SAMEDISPLAYFORMAT)
End Property
```

From [vbAccelerator.com](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Tips/Working_with_Multiple_Monitors/article.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much guru.... I was planning to do with C++ MFC Application, and try to add to VB. anyway thank you so much...